# Slow .value function within for loop

Tags: performance, excel, for-loop, find, vba

I have been using this site for a while and it has been really useful for me. First of all I want to thank all contributors for this. However I faced a problem and could not find a solution for that.

I'm not a professional coder or programmer, I am only using excel VBA to improve some reporting tools which we use at work. That is why I may have done really basic mistakes, please do not hate me :)

So, I am trying to create basic inventory follow-up tool which is going to contain some part numbers in the main sheet (Followup Sheet) and every day responsible is going to paste some values to incoming sheet (WebDOS Pivot), with my macro I am planning to look for incoming part numbers within existing ones and if it is there input the incoming value to the related cell.

My .find function is working good, however when I add the code to copy the value to related cell macro starts to run really slow. Do you guys have any idea what I am doing wrong, or how can I improve the performance of this code? Thank you in advance.

```
Dim WebDOSLastRow As Long
Dim WDS As Worksheet
Dim FUS As Worksheet
Dim PUS As Worksheet
Dim SearchResult As Range
Set WDS = Sheets("WebDOS Pivot")
Set FUS = Sheets("Followup Sheet")
Set PUS = Sheets("Part Usage Pivot")
WebDOSLastRow = WDS.Range("A3").End(xlDown).Row
    For i = 5 To WebDOSLastRow - 1
        With FUS.Range("E:E")
            Set SearchResult = .Find(What:=WDS.Range("A" & i).Value, _
            After:=Range("E5"), _
            LookIn:=xlValues, _
            LookAt:=xlWhole, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False)
            If Not SearchResult Is Nothing Then
                FUS.Range("K" & SearchResult.Row).Value = WDS.Range("C" & i).Value + FUS.Range("K" & SearchResult.Row).Value
                Else
                'Coding Will Come Here for not found items
            End If
        End With
            Application.StatusBar = "Searching " & i & "/" & WebDOSLastRow
    Next
        Application.StatusBar = False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve my problem right after posting here, which shows that I did not try hard before :), so simply switching to manual calculation solved slow running problem. Here is the new code.

```
WebDOSLastRow = WDS.Range("A3").End(xlDown).Row

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual '<---- Switching to manual calculation

For i = 5 To WebDOSLastRow - 1
    With FUS.Range("E:E")
        Set SearchResult = .Find(What:=WDS.Range("A" & i).Value, _
        After:=Range("E5"), _
        LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False)
        If Not SearchResult Is Nothing Then
            FUS.Range("K" & SearchResult.Row).Value = WDS.Range("C" & i).Value + FUS.Range("K" & SearchResult.Row).Value
            Else
            'Coding Will Come Here for not found items
        End If
    End With
    Application.StatusBar = "Searching " & i & "/" & WebDOSLastRow
Next
    Application.StatusBar = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```